# Prevent css being updated on drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When I set disabled on a drop :

```
$( "myDiv" ).droppable(
{
    drop: function( event, ui )  {
        $(this).droppable('disable');
    }
});
```

The CSS of the dropped element is updated, the background is greyed out. Can I override this to leave the look of the element as is ?

Comment: write your code in jsfiddle.net & post the fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts I was unable to reproduce this on jsfiddle. After alot of digging I found this : http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6039?cversion=0&cnum_hist=1 and I think I encountered same bug. Fix for me was to remove the class 'ui-state-disabled' when setting 'disabled' like so :

```
$("#"+this.id).droppable('disable').removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

Any more info around this issue much appreciated.